# Normalizing image dataset

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, normalization

I would like to normalize my image dataset and save those normalized images with the same file and folder names as the original dataset.
Is there something wrong with this code as I try to plot the histogram of the channels to check whether the images are correctly normalized or not, I get two peaks at 0 and 1 for the histogram of red pixels (as an example) . Am I doing something wrong. Is the code for normalizing all the dataset correct. How can I make sure all the images are correctly normalized and How to plot a visualization to check this normalization.

Also how can I do scaling of the dataset in addition to the normalization and is it a necessary step when processing images.

```
import os
import cv2

def normalization(img_path):
    image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    n_img = cv2.normalize(image, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
    return n_img

input_root_dir = 'Path to orginal dataset'
output_root_dir = 'Path to the output Folder for saving images'


for dir, _, file in os.walk(input_root_dir):
    for i in file:
        if file.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg')):

            input_image_path = os.path.join(dir, file)

            
            relative_dir = os.path.relpath(dir, input_root_dir)
            output_dir = os.path.join(output_root_dir, relative_dir)
            if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
                os.makedirs(output_dir)

            output_image_path = os.path.join(output_dir, file)

            
            n_img = normalization(input_image_path)
            cv2.imwrite(output_image_path, (n_img * 255).astype('uint8')) 
            print(f"Processing: {input_image_path}")
            print(f"Saving to: {output_image_path}")
```

Comment: I tried this on a handful of images I already had, and it seemed to produce reasonable results. The histograms from both before and after look similar, with a change of scale. Are you sure that your image's pixels are not naturally clustered around 0 and 255?

Comment: More generally - is it useful to scale your images by min/max? 99% of the time, your images are going to have a totally black pixel and a totally white pixel, so this will be equivalent to dividing by 255. Most image neural networks I can think of just use a constant division / multiplication.

Comment: Can you please post how you were able to visualize the normalized image, Also is it a correct approach to multiply by 255 when saving the images. I am having a 0 and 1 peaks when looking at the pixel values versus frequency @Nick ODell

Comment: I used matplotlib to visualize it. `norm = normalization("house.jpg"); plt.imshow(norm[:, :, ::-1]); plt.show()`. Also tried `plt.hist(array[:, :, 0].flatten()); plt.show()` to visualize blue channel histogram.

Comment: `Also is it a correct approach to multiply by 255 when saving the images` I think that's fine. It lets you use standard image formats. It's not impossible to save images in floating point format between 0 and 1, but it's harder. There's something to be said for making it easy to view images inside your data pipeline so you can tell visually if you've messed something up.